# Passing an id through a form to a foreign key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

What I'm trying to do is create a family through a form, then save this family and after that we are redirect to a minorstudent form where you can create a student that is link to the family you just created before.

Everything on my models, migrations is okay because in my controller I can see the student and the family, but my problems is when I create the family I want to pass the 'id' of the table 'familly' to the table family which has in its table the foreign key 'familly_id' ...But I don't know how to do it on my controllers. Thanks for the future help.

```
else {
          $minorstudent = new Minorstudent;
          $minorstudent->first_name = $request->first_name;
          $minorstudent->last_name = $request->last_name;
          $minorstudent->phone_number = $request->phone_number;
          $minorstudent->street_address = $request->street_address;
          $minorstudent->postal_code = $request->postal_code;
          $minorstudent->city = $request->city;
          $minorstudent->email_address = $request->email_address;
          $minorstudent->level = $request->level;
          if ($request->school!="none") {
              $minorstudent->school()->associate($request->school);
          }
          $minorstudent->save();
          return redirect('/familly');
        }
```

And I want the 'id' of the family I created before being pass to the minorstudent into 'familly_id' which is a foreign key.

```
 else {
        $minorstudent = Minorstudent::where('id',$request->id)->first();
        if ( $request->get('add_student_next') !== null ) {
          $familly = new Familly;
          $familly->first_name = $request->first_name;
          $familly->last_name = $request->last_name;
          $familly->phone_number = $request->phone_number;
          $familly->street_address = $request->street_address;
          $familly->postal_code = $request->postal_code;
          $familly->city = $request->city;
          $familly->email_address = $request->email_address;
          $familly->absence = 1;
          $familly->rules = 1;
          $minorstudent->familly_id()->attach($familly); 
          $familly->save();
          return redirect("/familly/id/student/new");
        }
```

This the family controllers (form) where you create the family and after that you are redirect to the minorstudent form

Don't worry about the else at the beginning

Comment: if i get you clearly, after saving family youre redirecting to student route and you needed the family id you just saved. if so, after ```$familly->save();``` you can get the id with ```$id = $familly->id```, then you pass the ```$id``` to the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

After creating Family you simply want to pass family_id to the student form and save the family_id in the student table (assuming family and student are two tables).

```
 $familly->save();
 return redirect()->route( 'familly.student.new' )->with( [ 'id' => $familly->id ] );
```

The reason I have written $familly->id  is because in your migration id will be the primary key for family.

You also want to create a relationship between family and student (assuming family and student are two tables)to access the data cleanly. In your family model write

```
class Family extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the student for the family.
     */
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
    }
}
```

In your Student model

```
class Student extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the family that has students.
     */
    public function family()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Family::class);
    }
}
```

Also, move the database part to the model.

Answer (score 0):

On the second else instead this line:

```
  $minorstudent->familly_id()->attach($familly);
```

Try this:

```
$minorstudent->update(['familly_id' => $family->id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

thank for everyone who helped me !

The solution was :

FamillyController: This is the function who receive the id of the familly I created before :

```
 else {
      $minorstudent = new Minorstudent;
      $minorstudent->familly()->associate($id);
      $minorstudent->update(["familly_id" => $id]);
      $minorstudent->first_name = $request->first_name;
      $minorstudent->last_name = $request->last_name;
      $minorstudent->phone_number = $request->phone_number;
      $minorstudent->street_address = $request->street_address;
      $minorstudent->postal_code = $request->postal_code;
      $minorstudent->city = $request->city;
      $minorstudent->email_address = $request->email_address;
      $minorstudent->level = $request->level;
      $minorstudent->option = $request->option;
      if ($request->school!="none") {
          $minorstudent->school()->associate($request->school);
      }
    
      $minorstudent->save();
     
      return redirect('/familly');
```